# Ho to style post content for Wordpress API?

Tags: rest-api

I'm completely new to Wordpress and Wordpress API. I managed to understand how the API works and how to fetch data from it on my Vue application.

Now, I have an issue with my posts. I am trying to display my post content which I created using the Classic Editor (wysiwyg) but in my API, the styling is not there for images and the rest of the content. I see only my title which I centered had its style applied.

Is there a workaround for this or is there something I am missing? How do I ensure my blog post is customizable on my front-end?

Comment: You should include some code; if you're styling content in the WYSIWYG editor but not seeing that styling in what gets sent to your Vue app, then chances are it's being stripped out at some point.  If you go into the DB you'll see that it's in there under 'post_content' so you have to figure where in your code it's being removed.

Comment: What styling are you talking about? Any styles that are applied using classes in HTML, like `aligncenter` etc. would be styled by your theme. If you're consuming that content in a Vue application then you need to include styling for those classes in your application. The API responses aren't supposed to include styling (unless added with inline styles).